# How to rewrite TSQL query for use in Microsoft Access 2003: TSQL Convert

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I'd like to rewrite this query for Microsoft Access 2003:

```
SELECT t1.PERSONID
       ,t1.CARDEVENTDATE
       ,MIN(t1.CARDEVENTTIME1) AS Intime
       ,MAX(t2.CARDEVENTTIME1) AS Outtime 

FROM (   SELECT PERSONID
                , CARDEVENTDATE
                , FUNCTIONKEY
                , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUBSTRING(CARDEVENTTIME, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CARDEVENTTIME, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CARDEVENTTIME, 5, 2), 8) 
                 AS CARDEVENTTIME1  
         FROM T_CARDEVENT 
         WHERE      (FUNCTIONKEY = 'A')) AS t1 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PERSONID
                                 ,CARDEVENTDATE, CARDEVENTDAY, FUNCTIONKEY
                                 ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUBSTRING(CARDEVENTTIME, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CARDEVENTTIME, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CARDEVENTTIME, 5, 2), 8) 
                                  AS CARDEVENTTIME 
                      FROM T_CARDEVENT AS T_CARDEVENT_3) 
           AS t2 
           ON t1.PERSONID = t2.PERSONID 
           AND t1.CARDEVENTDATE = t2.CARDEVENTDATE   
           GROUP BY t1.PERSONID, t1.CARDEVENTDATE )
```

The above works in SQL Server, but in Access I've tried to run this query. **It produces an error in `convert`**.

How should I modify my query to suit Access 2003? What's the suitable equivalent for [TSQL's Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function in Access 2003?

Comment: Please format your query so that it isn't an unreadable blob.

Comment: If you want someone to convert your query for you(!), perhaps you could help the reader by at least formatting so that is readable.

Comment: There is no such thing as "SQL Server 2003".

Comment: Did you delete your previous question ? If so, why and did you find the answer ?

Comment: @Edelcom, I find the solution for that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample below may suit, if you use SQL Server compatible Syntax.

In t2, you appear to be missing 1 from CARDEVENTTIME, so I added it to give CARDEVENTTIME1. You also appear to have an extra bracket at the end.

```
SELECT t1.PERSONID
       ,t1.CARDEVENTDATE
       ,MIN(t1.CARDEVENTTIME1) AS Intime
       ,MAX(t2.CARDEVENTTIME1) AS Outtime 

FROM (   SELECT PERSONID
                , CARDEVENTDATE
                , FUNCTIONKEY
                , CDate(Mid(CARDEVENTTIME, 1, 2) + ':' + Mid(CARDEVENTTIME, 3, 2) + ':' + Mid(CARDEVENTTIME, 5, 2)) 
                 AS CARDEVENTTIME1  
         FROM T_CARDEVENT 
         WHERE      (FUNCTIONKEY = 'A')) AS t1 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PERSONID
                                 ,CARDEVENTDATE, CARDEVENTDAY, FUNCTIONKEY
                                  , CDate(Mid(CARDEVENTTIME, 1, 2) + ':' + Mid(CARDEVENTTIME, 3, 2) + ':' + Mid(CARDEVENTTIME, 5, 2)) 
                                  AS CARDEVENTTIME1
                      FROM T_CARDEVENT AS T_CARDEVENT_3) 
           AS t2 
           ON t1.PERSONID = t2.PERSONID 
           AND t1.CARDEVENTDATE = t2.CARDEVENTDATE   
           GROUP BY t1.PERSONID, t1.CARDEVENTDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the normal Access function Str(...) ?

Update: Dont have Access here to try it, but isn't there a parameter which tells Access to just use the sql as pass throught (without modifying it) ?